# Aplicar mascara no back-end Java

Tags: java, regex

Alguém sabe como incluir uma mascara a partir de um regex em uma string?
Por exemplo, possuo a o seguinte regex`String pattern = "\\d{2}[/]\\d{3}.\\d{3}[/]\\d{4}";`e uma variável com o seguinte valor `String numeroProcesso = "010000012018";`. Quero uma função que me retorne o seguinte resultado: `numeroProcessoComRegex = "01/000.001/2018"`. Isso seria simples se meu regex não fosse dinamico, porém o mesmo pode ser alterado o pattern a qualquer momento.

Comment: Acho que o `.` da regex era para ser `\\.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver seu problema seria usando a classe MaskFormatter.

Exemplo:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "##/###.###/####";
        String numeroProcesso = "010000012018";
        System.out.println(format(pattern, numeroProcesso));
    }

    private static String format(String pattern, Object value) {
        MaskFormatter mask;
        try {
            mask = new MaskFormatter(pattern);
            mask.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
            return mask.valueToString(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Imports:

```
    import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
    import java.text.ParseException;
```

Comment: o problema está justamente nesse pattern fixo, no caso precisa ser regex, pois o formato da numeração muda conforme a necessidade do cliente. No meu front-end já tenho essa validação, porém precisei implementar uma integração e o numero vem sem mascara de outro sistema.

Comment: Como o padrão é alterado? Como isso acontece?

Comment: Tenho um propertie com regex do padrão de número para cada cliente, por exemplo para o cliente A é 00/000.000/0000, para o cliente B 00/0000, para C 00/00/0000/000. É algo legado já, infelizmente mudar a lógica é muito custoso, por isso eu queria tentar achar uma forma de fazer isso com regex ao invés do pattern sugerido.